# Get priority of trucks (Advent of Code 2022: Day 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from collections.abc import Iterator
import itertools
import pathlib
import string


PRIORITY = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(string.ascii_letters, start=1)}


def parse(f: pathlib.Path) -> Iterator[str]:
    yield from f.read_text().splitlines()


def parse_line_blocks(f: pathlib.Path, block_size: int) -> Iterator[list[str]]:
    lines = f.read_text().splitlines()
    for chunk_offset in range(0, len(lines), block_size):
        yield lines[chunk_offset:chunk_offset + block_size]


def get_compartments(truck: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    half_way = len(truck) // 2
    return truck[:half_way], truck[half_way:]


def get_shared(*args: str) -> str:
    shared = set.intersection(*map(set, args))
    return shared.pop()


def get_truck_shared_letter(truck: str) -> str:
    return get_shared(*get_compartments(truck))


def get_priority(char: str) -> int:
    return PRIORITY[char]


def part_1(f: pathlib.Path) -> int:
    shared = map(get_truck_shared_letter, parse(f))
    return sum(map(get_priority, shared))


def part_2(f: pathlib.Path) -> int:
    truck_blocks = parse_line_blocks(f, block_size=3)
    return sum(get_priority(get_shared(*block)) for block in truck_blocks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'input.txt'
    print(f'Part 1: {part_1(input_file)}')
    print(f'Part 2: {part_2(input_file)}')
```

### Rules

1. Each line in the input file represents a truck.
2. Lowercase a through z have "priority" of 1 through 26.
3. Uppercase A through Z have "priority" of 27 through 52.

#### First part

1. Divide each truck (string) into two equal string (first half, second half).
2. Find the single character that exists in both the first and the second part.
3. Find that character's priority.
4. Return the sum of all the priorities.

#### Second part

1. Each time, read 3 trucks from the file.
2. Find the shared character between all these 3 trucks.
3. Find that single character priority.
4. Return the sum of all the priorities.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you see "trucks" in the [description](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/3)? I read the problem as involving elves carrying rucksacks (backpacks/bags). Your code looks very good though.

Comment: Oops. LOL, so rucksacks it is XD. Thanks for the compliment :)